# Razor section inclusions from partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have section for scripts in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<html>
    <body>
    ...
        @RenderSection("FooterScript", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

I have view "Index.cshtml" that contains `@Html.RenderPartial("LinksBlock", someModel)`.
LinksBlock partial requires script file "links.js". I want to make links.js inclusion into FooterScript from my partial view, not from main view (main view don't know about dependencies of partial view), and I want to be sure, that if I use more than 1 LinksBlock in my view, only 1 links.js was included. Is it possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sections do not work with partial views. But you could write a pair of custom helpers that could be used in conjunction:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString RegisteredScripts(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var ctx = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext;
        var registeredScripts = ctx.Items["_scripts_"] as Stack<string>;
        if (registeredScripts == null || registeredScripts.Count < 1)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var script in registeredScripts)
        {
            var scriptBuilder = new TagBuilder("script");
            scriptBuilder.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";
            scriptBuilder.Attributes["src"] = script;
            sb.AppendLine(scriptBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
        }
        return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }

    public static void RegisterScript(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string script)
    {
        var ctx = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext;
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var registeredScripts = ctx.Items["_scripts_"] as Stack<string>;
        if (registeredScripts == null)
        {
            registeredScripts = new Stack<string>();
            ctx.Items["_scripts_"] = registeredScripts;
        }
        var src = urlHelper.Content(script);
        if (!registeredScripts.Contains(src))
        {
            registeredScripts.Push(src);
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@Html.RegisteredScripts()
```

and in your partial:

```
@{Html.RegisterScript("~/scripts/foo.js");}
```

Comment: What if I want to have possibility to add both script separated files and scripts that placed in partial view (for second I want to use key to identify and not register same scripts if partial view renders multiple times)?

Comment: I use .vsdoc files and for second way I want to retain Intellisence support (e.g. It should not work like Register("key", "<script type='..'>...</script>")  but Register("key", @{<script type='...'>...</script>}))

Comment: Great. Upvoted. I'm not going to use this yet but I want to add it to my codebase right now!!! :)

Comment: Darin, you are a godsend!! The solution is fantastic and we have put it to use immediately. Thank you-- We have made one modification, we are not sure about the use of Stack here (last in first out), so we have replaced it with a Queue (and instead of the foreach loop we use Dequeue to gradually empty out the collection). Was the use of Stack intentional and we have failed to see its benefits?