# MVC 4 - How to pass a template to an html helper method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to have all my scripts at the bottom of the page, problem is when I have a Partial View I cannot use the "RenderSection" approach. Found a great example of how to add a HtmlHelper extension which takes the name of a script file, loads into a stack, then another helper renders that out on the base layout:
[Razor section inclusions from partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655113/razor-section-inclusions-from-partial-view)

That's great - but I don't want to have to create an entire JS file for a little chunk of script, or maybe even HTML, that I want to drop in. And I don't want to pass it all as a string, I want the nice formatting and intellisense, so I want to use a template ie:

```cs
@{Html.AddScript("test", @<text>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RefreshPreview() {
        $('#AutoReplyHtml_Preview').html(
            $('#htmlTemplate').html()
                .replace('@@MESSAGE_TITLE@@', $('#AutoReplySubject').val())
                .replace('@@PRE_HEADER@@', $('#AutoReplyPreHeader').val())
                .replace('@@MESSAGE_BODY@@', $('#AutoReplyHtml').val())
        );

        $('#AutoReplyPlainText_Preview').html(
            $('#plainTextTemplate').html()
                .replace('@@MESSAGE_BODY@@', $('#AutoReplyPlainText').val())
        );
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        RefreshPreview();
    });
</script>
</text>);}
```

Problem is - how to I get the value of the template into my method, I have this code which complies, but no clue how to get the data out of the "code" parameter:

```cs
    public static string AddScript(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string title, Func<object, object> code) {
    var ctx = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext;
    Dictionary<string, string> scripts = ctx.Items["HtmlHelper.AddScript"] as Dictionary<string, string>;
    if (scripts == null) {
        scripts = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        ctx.Items.Add("HtmlHelper.AddScript", scripts);
    }

    scripts.Add(title, code.ToString()); //Doens't work!

    return string.Empty;
}
```

How do I need to tweak the delegate parameter to get the value inside the  template??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The helper architecture is designed so that it can accomodate scenarios where you are providing a template that will operate, for example, on each item in a list.  In such a scenario, you'd of course want to be able to pass it the "current" item when iterating through the list.

However, in other scenarios (such as yours), there *is no current item*.  Yet, as you've discovered, you still have to declare a delegate as a parameter to your method that defines a method that consumes one parameter.   That's ok -- since you're not consuming that argument in your helper  (you don't make use of the somewhat magical `item` parameter in your template) you can just pass it `null` in your implementation.  Preferably, declare your parameter as a `Func<object, IHtmlString>` rather than a `Func<object, object>`, but regardless, just invoke `code(null).ToString()` to get the HTML-encoded string you need to render.

Comment: Perfect! that is exactly what I need - still very much a newbie when it comes to Func - just 1 tweak, had to make it IHtmlString: `public static IHtmlString AddBottomContent(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string title, Func<object, IHtmlString> code)`  then the "code(null).ToString()" to dump it into a dictionary for later output worked!

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  I use `HelperResult` in my code (which implements `IHtmlString`), but I'm glad you mentioned it; perhaps `IHtmlString` is more general and is what I should be using in my code.