# How to check if MVC bundle exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there a way to test if a bundle exists before trying to render it?

I want to do something like this:

```
@{
    var bundleName = GetBundleName();
}

@if (Scripts.BundleExists(bundleName))
{
    @Scripts.Render(bundleName)
}
```

Obviously, `Scripts.BundleExists()` isn't real, but it there something build in that does this?  Or do I have to implement this myself?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042524/is-there-a-way-to-determine-an-asp-net-mvc-bundle-is-rendered-before-or-not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the bundles in the View by: 
 `var bl = System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles;` 
 Then you can search the collection for a specific bundle by path as registered in BundleConfig. After that check if the path or any of the included paths exist.

Comment: great thanks.  For what it's worth, I used `BundleTable.Bundles.Any(y => y.Path == bundleName)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way (nor was I able to find a way) for you to do this that is built into the framework. If you really have to do this, I would point you to a solution by Herman.

[Asp.Net MVC Bundling, best way to detect missing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802800/asp-net-mvc-bundling-best-way-to-detect-missing-file/25784663#25784663)

Are your bundles dynamic? If not, I would suggest that this may not be something you need. Once you have them setup correctly the first time, they shouldn't fail.